# RevolutionPlot3D: Inconsistency between Mathematica 8/Linux and Mathematica 9/OSX

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

The following code runs error-free in *Mathematica* 8.0 under Linux.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
x = RandomReal[{0.1, Pi}, 100];
g[t_] := x[[Ceiling[t]]]/Max[x]
RevolutionPlot3D[
    {g[t] Sin[t]^2 + 1, t},
    {t, 0, 5},                    (* see comment in 'EDIT' regarding the t=0 case *)
    {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

The same exact code produces the following errors when is executed in *Mathematica* 9.0.1 under Mac OSX (copied by hand):

> Part:pspec : Part specification Ceiling[t] is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers.>>
>   General::stop : Further output of Part::pspec will be suppressed during this calculation.>>

**EDIT**: `g[0]` yields `0.32669List`, but changing the domain to say `{1,5}` does *not* fix anything.

Despite the errors an almost original image is produced.

I used an evaluation monitor to check whether `g[t]` is properly calculated like:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
x = RandomReal[{0.1, Pi}, 100];
g[t_] := x[[Ceiling[t]]]/Max[x]
RevolutionPlot3D[
    {g[t] Sin[t]^2 + 1, t},
    {t, 0, 5},                    (* see comment in 'EDIT' regarding the t=0 case *)
    {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints->3,  (* restrict points or else we will get flooded *)
    EvaluationMonitor :> Print["t=", t, ", g[t]=", g[t]]]
```

The output I get is of the form:

> ... Part::pspec : ...
>   t[2.5x10^-6, g[t]=0.40655
>   t[2.5], g[t]=0.811194
>   ...

which looks ok.

Finally, I don't think that my problem has to do with `RevolutionPlot3D[]` per se, but rather with the way I define and call `g[t]` in this context.

Comment: The same on Win7, and if you take `{g[t] Sin[t]^2 + 1, t,1}` to `ParametricPlot3D` it will produce the same error.

Comment: Makes some sense @Kuba since `RevolutionPlot3D[]` is a special case of `ParametricPlot3D[]` according to the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems on Win and OSX *Mathematica* is smuggling something non numerical to `g[]`.

This seems to do the job on Win7:

```
g[t_?NumberQ] := x[[Ceiling[t]]]/Max@x
```

`PatternTest` will help you but I don't know why :)

---

My first thought was it is lack of `Evaluate` but it does not seem to be the issue. Also, if `Ceiling` called directly, there is no error:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{Ceiling[t] Sin[t]^2 + 1, t},...
```

---

There is also the thing about

```
g[0]
```

> 0.321071 List

what is obvious but changing `t` domain to `{1,5}` does not fix anything.

Comment: I confirm @Kuba that with the pattern test it works fine. I will leave the question as it is for now and unless someone explains this behavior I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I was using `{0.1, ...}` in the domain but it didn't make any difference. Thanks for bringing it up though.

Comment: @Zet I'm glad it helps but I'm curious what's the matter :)